# AD Role provider for SharePoint 2010

Tags: active-directory, forms-authentication

I'm trying to set up a Sharepoint 2010 solution with form based authenication (claims). ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider workes find as memebership provider, we need the be able to add ad groups using forms based.

Is there a good AD role provider that can be used with SharePoint form based authentication in SharePoint 2010.

Comment: Either I didn't get your question or I am missing something, but if you want to use AD for authentication why go for Forms Authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this one: "Microsoft.Office.Server.Security.LdapRoleProvider, Microsoft.Office.Server, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"